# MySQL - ranking by count() and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, rank

I've got my mysql table `posts`, where all posts of my forum are stored. It's like this:

```
id      uid      thread      post      title      text      time
(int)   (int)    (varchar)   (int)     (varchar)  (text)    (int)
```

Now I want to show the rank (ranking of number of posts) on the user profiles. I've tried something like this:

```
set @rownum := 0;
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, uid, count(id)
FROM `posts` GROUP BY uid ORDER BY count(id)
```

But it returns not the right data. The uid and count(id) match, but the rank is wrong.
My entry is like:

```
rank     uid     count(id)
  1        1        214
```

I'm user 1, and I've got 214 posts, but that's not rank 1.
There are other entries like:

```
rank     uid     count(id)
  8       22        674
```

---

How can I get the query to put out the right rank?

Comment: That's `ORDER BY count(id) DESC` right?

Comment: @mellamokb it doesn't work with DESC and ASC

Comment: What do you want to happen if two or more users have the same number of posts?

Comment: @pilcrow hm, i think this doesn't matter, it should just order ist per uid secondary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need your entire result set grouped by user ID first and ordered... then apply the ranking

```
select
      @rownum := @rownum +1 as rank,
      prequery.uid,
      prequery.PostCount
   from
      ( select @rownum := 0 ) sqlvars,
      ( SELECT uid, count(id) postCount
           from posts
           group by uid
           order by count(id) desc ) prequery
```

To get for a specific person, and problem attempting the "HAVING" clause, I would then wrap it up and then apply a where...

```
select WrappedQuery.* 
   from ( entire query from above ) WrappedQuery
   where WrappedQuery.uid = SinglePerson
```

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to return only one row for a specified uid?

Comment: @Ninov, yes, just add to the outermost part of the query...   HAVING prequery.uid = IDOfPersonWanted

Comment: @DRapp, are you sure about that HAVING guidance?  I get `ERROR 1463 (42000): Non-grouping field ... is used in HAVING clause` if I add that to a substantively similar MySQL ROW_NUMBER hack.

Comment: Hm this returns rank=1 for uid 1 and (Null) for all other uids... **edit:** it returns rank=1 for each uid, which has any posts :(

Comment: @ninov, revised to wrap answer up one more level.